# Android TabActivity in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-activity, android-intent

How to display TabActivity in AlertDialog?
I know that it's a little bit tricky, as we should run TabActivity as normal activity,

e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyClass.this, Settings.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

where Settings - TabActvivity.

The only way I know it to set view for AlertDialog, but it will don't work.

```
View view = (View) ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
  .inflate(R.layout.settings, null);
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("AlertDialog").setView(view).show();
```

Is there any way to show TabActivity in AlertDialog?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sort of conflating the concept of Views and Activities here, but probably the easiest way to do what you want is to set your `TabActivity`'s theme to [`Theme.Dialog`](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#alerts) and start it, instead of using an `AlertDialog` and trying to wrap an `Activity` inside a popup inside another `Activity`. For your own sanity's sake, don't go down that road into Inception-type territory.

Answer (score 3):

I wont really recommend this approach but since you have requested the behavior heres a sample code:

Heres a Tab *layout*, which has a `EditText` in **tab1** and a `Button` in **tab2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="TextBox"
    />

    </LinearLayout>
<Button android:id="@+id/tab2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="A semi-random button"
/>
</FrameLayout></LinearLayout></TabHost>
```

Code to inflate this layout to a `AlertDialog`

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflator=getLayoutInflater();
    View view=inflator.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

    TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)view.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Clock");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Button");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    builder.create().show();
```

As I said **THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED APPROACH** create a theme instead as suggested by *Yoni Samlan* above.

Comment: if i have a inflator view so how can i pass ID to setContent ?